# Alfresco 5 CMIS indexing bug?

Tags: alfresco, alfresco-share

I've set up alfresco with a custom type. I have also set up a custom form for searching the fields of the custom type. This all works perfectly until I add CMIS into the mix. 
When I set the content type of a document to my custom type using CMIS, I find that searching on the fields results in nothing. It would appear that setting the type through CMIS prevents the content from being indexed. (I have also tested CMIS queries on the properties and this comes up with no results as well for the latter situation)

Has anyone else found this problem? Or can someone else replicate this so that I can accept that it is a bug?

Thanks,
Sean

EDIT:
After further testing this seems to work with the old CMIS 1.0 path:
alfresco/api/-default-/public/cmis/versions/1.0/atom
Whenever I use the CMIS 1.1 path, all copied documents are not being indexed:
alfresco/api/-default-/public/cmis/versions/1.1/atom

Comment: After some more testing I have found that it is simply related to copying the document with CMIS - copied documents will not be indexed - NOTE that this works with CMIS 1.0 but not with CMIS 1.1

Comment: If you have not already, please create an issue at http://issues.alfresco.com with Alfresco version info and steps to reproduce.